# Tensorflow: 'tf.get_default_session()` after sess=tf.Session() is None

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was trying to figure out why `tf.get_default_session()` always returns `None` type:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

default = tf.get_default_session()
default == None # True
```

I do not know why `default = tf.get_default_session()` is `None` since I thought it should return the previous session.
Could anyone figures out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Some more context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564185/tensorflow-setting-default-session-using-as-default-enter/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just creating a `tf.Session()` doesn't make it a default. This is basically the difference between [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) and [`tf.InteractiveSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession):

```py
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(tf.get_default_session())    # this is not None!
```

Unlike `tf.InteractiveSession`, a `tf.Session` becomes a default only inside `with` block (it's a context manager):

```py
sess = tf.Session()
with sess:
  print(tf.get_default_session())  # this is not None!
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. When `with` ( it looks like using `__enter__`), how Tenserflow brought the Default Session? The tool built the TF Graph again or bring it from some memory location?