# Tensorflow: setting default session using as_default().__enter__()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I write

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Session()
x.as_default().__enter__()
print(tf.get_default_session()) # prints "None"
```

Why am I not accomplishing getting x to be the default session? I know I could just do it inside a "with" block, but I'm wondering why this isn't working.

Note that if I write

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session().as_default():
    print(tf.get_default_session()) # shows <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x114217a90>
```

How are these two pieces of code doing different things?

Also, if I just write

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session()
```

will that create a nameless session that I have no way to close, so it will just run until I restart my kernel? Is there a way to check which sessions are currently open?

Comment: Things can get bad even if you do name the tensorflow session.

Comment: If you do not name it, then tf will have no idea which ops it has to run under which session.

Comment: @chrisz Can you explain a bit more? Like if I leave it open for too long? (Or you could just provide a reference)

Comment: @EricAuld Please, try to run repeated inferences without closing the Session (`__exit__`) and to measure inferencing times. I guess if  the processing time is constant, your method would be safe.

Answer (score 7):

Simple fix:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Session().__enter__()
print(tf.get_default_session())
```

Result:

```
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f6855cbafd0>
```

Cause:

`as_default()` is returning a context manager, not a session, you're calling enter on a `_GeneratorContextManager` object when you mean to enter a `Session` object.

```
>>> tf.Session().as_default()
<contextlib._GeneratorContextManager object at 0x7f6820805a58>
>>> tf.Session()
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f6820805898>
```

---

**Update**

To answer your (initially perplexing) follow up question:

What you are doing with the with statement is entering and exiting the context manager. This is causing the default session to be set and unset. But it is not opening and closing your session (it appears, this was confusing to me and I'm only seeing it after some experimentation). Try this code out to see it operate:

```
>>> print(tf.get_default_session())
None

>>> x = tf.Session()
>>> print(tf.get_default_session())
None

>>> with x.as_default():
...     print(tf.get_default_session())
... 
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f09eb9fb550>
>>> print(x)
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f09eb9fb550>
```

We see at the end of those statements that your session never closed, but along the way we see that the default session was set and unset as expected.

Using the standard with statement both closes the session **and** sets/unsets the default session.

```
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
...     print(tf.get_default_session())
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f09eb9fbbe0>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused: when I say `with tf.Session().as_default()`, isn't `__enter__()` called on the thing that `tf.Session().as_default()` returns?

Comment: Yes, but the thing `tf.Session().as_default()` was returning was not the same as what `tf.Session()` was returning. I've never used `tf.Session().as_default()` so I can't offer an explanation as to what `as_default()` is doing here exactly. I just noted that it wasn't returning a session.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what it's doing, `as_default()` was actually changing the global default session, so it's not returning something useful, it's actually updating the global setting. This might be useful if you have multiple sessions running and you want to switch which one is the current global default.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. On the subject of `with`, how are the two blocks of code that I mention in my (edited) question doing different things? Specifically, when I use `with`, isn't `__enter__()` always called on the thing returned by whatever follows `with`?

Comment: Thank you! You've clarified that the two pieces of code do different things. I think this means I am confused about how `with` works. Doesn't `with` just call `__enter__()` on the thing that is returned by whatever follows `with`? It can't, right, because the two pieces of code I wrote do different things. (I said `x.as_default().__enter__()` and then I said `with x.as_default()`. BTW let me know if I'm asking too many follow-ups

Comment: It's a good question, threw me for a loop! :)  `tf.Session()` creates the session, then you called `.as_default()` on the session which set it as the default. `with` called `__enter__()` on the context manager returned by `.as_default()`. So using `.as_default()` in the `with` statement returned the wrong thing to call `__enter__()` on. You're supposed to call `__enter__()` on the session.

Comment: Right, it makes more sense to call `__enter__()` on the session itself. But I'm still confused on why my two pieces of code produced different results. In both cases my code should have called `__enter__()` on the context manager (which admittedly makes less sense). But when I used the `with` block, it knew what the default session was. When I didn't use the `with` block, it didn't know about a default session. How could this be if `with` is just calling `__enter__()` on whatever is returned by `with`? (In this case, it returns a context manager)