# Implementing with block manually produces different things

Tags: python, tensorflow, contextmanager

Suppose I write

```
with some_method()
    ...
```

My impression is that the `with` command starts by calling the `__enter__()` method on whatever is returned by `some_method()`. (I believe the thing returned by `some_method()` is called a "context manager", which just means it has methods called `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`.)

I tried calling `__enter__()` manually, and I got something different from what I expected. This specific example came up in the context of TensorFlow, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with TensorFlow as such.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Session()
x.as_default().__enter__()
print(tf.get_default_session())
```

prints `None`, and

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session().as_default().__enter__()
print(tf.get_default_session())
```

prints `None`, but

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session().as_default():
    print(tf.get_default_session())
```

prints `<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x114217a90>`.

I have posted essentially the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564185/tensorflow-setting-default-session-using-as-default-enter), but I made the mistake of editing it too many times, until by the end it wasn't asking what it started out asking. So I'm just recreating the question.

Comment: This sounds like it could be related to the context manager getting reclaimed. The `with` statement keeps a reference to the context manager (or at least, a reference to its `__exit__` method, which usually has a reference to the context manager), but you're discarding it. Trying saving `x.as_default()` to a variable.

Comment: Yeah, many context managers have a `close` method (or equivalent private thing) that's called in `__del__` as well as `__exit__`. (It makes sense for files and many other context managers, and some do it even though it doesn't make sense just by analogy with files etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you're discarding the context manager. Very few context managers are designed to be discarded after `__enter__`, without calling `__exit__`, and they may behave unpredictably if you do that. Some of them automatically call the equivalent of `__exit__` when garbage collected, and some behave in stranger ways.

In this particular case, I believe `tf.Session().as_default()` eventually delegates to a [generator-based context manager](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.7.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L4891). The underlying generator automatically calls its `close` method when garbage collected, which is very similar to calling the `__exit__` method of the context manager.

Comment: You're right, saving `x.as_default()` to a variable fixed it. When does "garbage collection" happen to an object, in general? Just want to understand what's going on here a bit better.

Comment: @EricAuld: In CPython, *usually* when the last reference to an object is cleared. In general, some time after an object is no longer reachable, or maybe never.